# Proper way to imitate infinite view and animate it on iOS

Tags: ios

I'm working on a control that looks like a wheel and is used for fast or precise scrolling of content. Here's an example from coach's eye app:
 [image: example scrolling wheel, coach's eye app]

My first take looks like this:
[image: my first take on scrolling wheel control]

Currently the vertical lines are implemented as set of UIViews. Sure enough these vertical line views could be easily replaced with image views to customise the look. 
 Each time user pans:

- I modify frame.origin.x on all of the vertical line views
- If some of the views go off screen - I remove them
- If there's a gap on the left or on the right I create new views to fit the place

When user finishes the pan gesture, I start repeat NSTimer (with like 0.05 of a second) to animate decelerating of wheel movement. On each loop of timer in a nutshell:

- Calculate distance to move lines and move them
- Calculate velocity deceleration amount and adjust the velocity

A couple of questions:

1. Are there any iOS frameworks (e.g. CoreGraphics, CoreAnimation, UIKitDynamics) that are suited better for implementing these tasks than UIKit APIs I have used?
2. Can you suggest a better / more correct way to implement "infinite scrolling wheel" control ?
3. Can you suggest a better way to implement deceleration after user finishes panning the wheel?

Thanks

Comment: Did you look at using a scroll view to manage the pan and deceleration and just update the contents based on the changing content offset in the delegate callbacks?

Comment: Could you please describe that in some more details (emulating infinite scrolling, moving content) in answer so that I could accept that?

Answer (score 0):

I had made my "**infinite scrolling wheel**" control by customizing [SSRollingButtonScrollView](https://github.com/ninefifteen/SSRollingButtonScrollView/tree/master). I think you should look at it once. I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Apple already have a nice algorithm implemented for acceleration and deceleration - in `UIScrollView`. And you can use that, behind the scenes, to control other views / interaction. This is enabled by connecting the pan gesture from the scroll view to another view and acting as the delegate of the scroll view.

Check out the [Enhancing User Experience with Scroll Views WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2012__hd/session_223__enhancing_user_experience_with_scroll_views.mov) for guidance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please share simplest implementation of the concept? I'd assume it should create / remove UIViews dynamically, like a UITableView. Probably a good idea to implement wrapper similar to data source. Or it might need to track scroll location and set it to last / first item when either of the ends is reached

Comment: I've added crude implementation of UIScrollView + datasource; I'd appreciate if you could add logic for looping the scroll view. https://github.com/truemetal/UIScrollView-InfiniteScrolling